# How to override the hash function of python data classes?

Tags: python, inheritance, hash, python-dataclasses

I am trying to write a base class for python `dataclasse` with a custom hash function as follows. However, when calling the child class's `hash` it does not use the custom hash function of the parent class.

```
import dataclasses
import joblib


@dataclasses.dataclass(frozen=True)
class HashableDataclass:

    def __hash__(self):
        print("Base class hash was called!")
        fields = dataclasses.fields(self)
        values = tuple(getattr(self, field.name) for field in fields)
        return int(joblib.hash(values), 16)


@dataclasses.dataclass(frozen=True)
class MyDataClass1(HashableDataclass):
    field1: int
    field2: str


obj1 = MyDataClass1(1, "Hello")
print(hash(obj1))
```

Is there a way to override hash function of data classes?

Comment: Why do you want to create a custom `__hash__`?

Comment: Some of the fields (e.g. Pandas DataFrame are not hashable)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#module-contents):

> If eq and frozen are both true, by default `dataclass()` will generate a `__hash__()` method for you. If eq is true and frozen is false, `__hash__()` will be set to None, marking it unhashable (which it is, since it is mutable). If eq is false, `__hash__()` will be left untouched meaning the `__hash__()` method of the superclass will be used (if the superclass is object, this means it will fall back to id-based hashing).

```
@dataclasses.dataclass(frozen=True, eq=False)  # <- HERE
class MyDataClass1(HashableDataclass):
    field1: int
    field2: str
```

Output:

```
>>> obj1 = MyDataClass1(1, "Hello")
Base class hash was called!
1356025966893372872
```

According the comment of [@user2357112](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2357112/user2357112), you can/should use (see reasons in comments)

```
@dataclasses.dataclass(frozen=True)
class MyDataClass1(HashableDataclass):
    __hash__ = HashableDataclass.__hash__  # <- HERE
    field1: int
    field2: str
```

Comment: This is broken. It will cause `==` comparisons to completely ignore `field1` and `field2`... which is all your fields, so [all instances of `MyDataClass1` will compare equal to each other](https://ideone.com/HRtca2).

Comment: Instead of passing `eq=False` to the `dataclass` decorator, you can explicitly assign `__hash__ = HashableDataclass.__hash__` inside the class body to use the parent `__hash__` implementation. [That avoids the `==` problems.](https://ideone.com/AfVCgD)

Comment: In this case inheritance is not really needed/useful. It is enough to write a hash_function, and do __hash__  =  hash_function